# Can we configure Trigger AS400 program after transaction commit on iSeries DB2?

Tags: triggers, db2, ibm-midrange

Can we configure Trigger on iSeries DB2 table which call AS400 program after transaction commit?

Answer (score 0):

No.

But you can have any changes made by the trigger program happen within the same commit cycle and be commited or rolled back at the same time as the triggering record.

If your trigger program external in RPGLE, make sure to use DFTACTGRP(*NO) ACTGRP(*CALLER) and that you open the files accessed under commitment control.

Answer (score 0):

Detect a commit on the iseries.

monitor the journal `RCVJRNE` for the commit transaction.